# how to install or update node modules(ionic, cordova) programmatically using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

Is there a way to programmatically check whether the module(ionic, cordova, gulp, bower) is installed already, if installed check whether update needed(is the installed version is the latest version), if so then update the package otherwise do nothing.

```
if (cordova == installed) {
   if (installed-version != latest-version) {
        npm update cordova -g;
   }
} else {
    npm install cordova -g;
}
```

At the moment i am doing the installation by
--setup.js file

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var setup = spawn(__dirname + '/setup.sh');
```

--setup.sh file

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g ionic
sudo npm install -g gulp
sudo npm install -g bower
```

The problem is each time when i run **node setup.js**, it install all over again though it is installed already.

Is there any way that i can check in the .js file before installing them.

I tried to use npmCheck but that does not help.

```
var npmCheck = require('npm-check');
npmCheck(options)
  .then(result);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `sudo` with `npm`.  `npm install` should handle everything you're asking for automatically (check for updates and update as appropriate -- otherwise do nothing). What do you mean it installs it again regardless?

Comment: i.e if cordova already installed then check for updates. If the installed version is the latest version then do not install it again. If i do not use sudo it fails on some system, so i am forcing to run as admin.